# Scaled image and text on hover in tandem (HTML,CSS)

Tags: html, css, hover, position

So, I've being driven insane by this simplistic issue
through css and html i want to scale image and text by hovering over the image i already got the image transition to work. But I'm really struggling to get text to scale below the image by the same amount. I want the text to follow image below it and scale in tandem to the image. Soz if i'm not very good :)

```css
img {
  width: 370px;
  height: 370px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

img:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/TSfq6rd.jpg" alt="">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/Pu8JqbA.jpg" alt="" style="padding-top: 300px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 20px">
<p style="position: absolute; padding-top: 600px">TEST</p>
```

Comment: You'd like to have images inline? How many?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "tandem"? Do you want that the text scales at the same time with the picture? If you want this is better to put both the picture and text insde a div.

Comment: div doesn't work for me it doesn't scale or apply any of me changes

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute for p isn't the right choice here.
Maybe try position: relative.

You can also remove the top padding and position from your inline style then.